# How to connect two parabolic paths in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a simple curve that consists of two parabolic paths, one horizontal, the other vertical.  So far, I am set on using `parabola`, but I can be swayed from doing so.  Below is my current code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through}
\tikzset{every label/.style = {label distance=2pt, inner sep=0pt}}
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}}
\tikzset{> = {Stealth[width=4pt, length=5pt, inset=1pt]}}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\unit}
\setlength{\unit}{0.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\unit, y=\unit, line width=2pt]
  % Begin axes
  \begin{scope}[line width=0.5pt]
    \draw[->] (-3.5,0) -- (5.5,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5.5);
    \foreach \x in {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    \draw (\x,2pt) -- (\x,-2pt) node [anchor=base, shift={(0,-8pt)}, inner sep=1pt] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {1, ..., 5}
    \draw (2pt,\y) -- (-2pt,\y) node [anchor=east, inner sep=1pt] {$\y$};
  \end{scope}
  % End axes
  \draw [rotate around={-90:(3,5)}](3,5) parabola (5.5,-1);
  \draw (3,5) parabola (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}      
\end{document}
```

The issue, evident in the included output, is how the two paths look "disjointed."  Is there a way to make them look like a continuous path?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two separate lines canot be joined. You need to draw both parabolas in single path. Try:

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, % <-- only this is needed 
                calc, intersections, through}

\newlength{\unit}
\tikzset{every label/.style = {label distance=2pt, inner sep=0pt},
         every node/.style={font=\footnotesize},
         > = {Stealth[width=4pt, length=5pt, inset=1pt]}
         }

\begin{document} 
\setlength{\unit}{0.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\unit, y=\unit, line width=2pt]
  % Begin axes
  \begin{scope}[line width=0.5pt]
    \draw[->] (-3.5,0) -- (5.5,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-0.1) -- (0,5.5);
    \foreach \x in {-3, -2,...,5}
        \draw (\x,2pt) -- ++ (0,-4pt) node[below] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {1,...,5}
        \draw (2pt,\y) -- ++ (-4pt,0) node[left] {$\y$};    
  \end{scope}% End axes
  % the first parabola start at (5,0) and end at (3,5) 
  % wherends start the second, rotated one
  % for this the bend of the first parabola is moved to the end of path
  \draw (5,0) parabola[bend at end] (3,5) {[rotate around={-90:(3,5)}] parabola (5.5,-1)} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Another simple solution, is to pass `line cap=round`, assuming rounded line joins are not an issue.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos, nice idea, howeve with your solution the "disjoin" is only less visible, but still present.

Comment: I know. But the OP has asked, and I quote, "to make them *look* like a continous path". `;D`

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos, you have right! Make answer with this solution :)

Answer (score 12):

Zarko's way is the most correct one, that's for sure. *But*, sometimes uniting the paths may be a ltttle tricky...

Then, there's a tricky way to make the paths *look* united, when in fact they are separate paths. To do this, one can use `line cap` key which is originally set to `butt`. In perpendicular joints is possible to use `line cap=rect` which will make the paths look like they're sharply joined, or for all cases `line cap=round` will make the paths look like they were roundly joined.*

Since the case here is a perpendicular join, it's possible to use `rect`, but I've added more drawings to the MWE, just to show how `line cap=round` always works but `rect` not always. Also on the top left corner there's examples of all three line caps so that the difference is appreciated.

[image]

The full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through}
\tikzset{every label/.style = {label distance=2pt, inner sep=0pt}}
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}}
\tikzset{> = {Stealth[width=4pt, length=5pt, inset=1pt]}}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\unit}
\setlength{\unit}{0.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\unit, y=\unit, line width=2pt]
  % Begin axes
  \begin{scope}[line width=0.5pt]
    \draw[->] (-3.5,0) -- (5.5,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5.5);
    \foreach \x in {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    \draw (\x,2pt) -- (\x,-2pt) node [anchor=base, shift={(0,-8pt)}, inner sep=1pt] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {1, ..., 5}
    \draw (2pt,\y) -- (-2pt,\y) node [anchor=east, inner sep=1pt] {$\y$};
  \end{scope}
  % End axes
  \draw[line cap=rect] [rotate around={-90:(3,5)}](3,5) parabola (5.5,-1);
  \draw (3,5) parabola (5,0);
  %%MWE ends here -- the rest is for demonstration purposes only
  \draw (1,0) -- (1,1);\draw[line cap=round] (1,1) -- +(135:1);
  \draw (2,0) -- (2,1);\draw[line cap=rect] (2,1) -- +(135:1);
  \draw (-3,5) -- +(1,0);\draw[ultra thin, white] (-3,5) -- +(1,0) node[font={\tiny\ttfamily},right,black]{butt};
  \draw[line cap=round] (-3,4.5) -- +(1,0); \draw[ultra thin, white] (-3,4.5) -- +(1,0) node[font={\tiny\ttfamily},right,black]{round};
  \draw[line cap=rect] (-3,4) -- +(1,0);\draw[ultra thin, white] (-3,4) -- +(1,0) node[font={\tiny\ttfamily},right,black]{rect};
\end{tikzpicture}      
\end{document}
```

<sub>*Of course this is only valid for lines of the same width, if the lines have different widths they wont be joined properly with this method...</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's very instructive. I marked Marko's answer as the correct one, but I'm also grateful for yours.

Comment: No worries there, you did the right thing. If you had marked this one I'd have suggested otherwise. I added this as it may be helpful to someone else. And you are very welcome! `:D`